# how to generate month wise data report in rails 3

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I Am new in rails, I have facing some problem regarding month wise data report.
I have a **user table** and **transaction table** with **has_many** association. transaction table has column **type**(buy or sell), **amount**(amount_value), and **created_at** and **updated_at** column and **user_id**.

How i can generate a user's month wise transaction report from this.

Comment: are you asking for a SQL query? or how to build it in rails? your question is not specific and you should provide some sample code. If you are talking about how you would get the data by month in mysql then that could be through the MONTH() method... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: @johnRuddell I am asking how to build in rails.

Comment: you need to provide some initial tries, even if its bad. you cant just ask us to write code for you... just google some examples, try to follow that, and then if you have problems post those here. thats what SO is for :) some sample links... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233422/generating-reports-efficiently-with-activerecord -------- https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/jasper-rails ------ https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/reporting ---- this was from a simple google search

Comment: @johnRuddell can you help me to write the sql for the same.

Comment: well that depends on what you want in your report. but what you can do is when you `SELECT your_data_here FROM transaction_table`... filter out what you want with `JOIN`ing the user table and using a `WHERE`... then add this to the end `GROUP BY MONTH(created_at)`.. which will group all of the data by the month it was done in

Answer (score 1):

Considering in your controller you have

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

meaning you are in the users `show` action you can get their transactions as follows:

```
@transactions = @user.transactions
```

That should return an array containing all the transactions if your naming is right.

**EDIT**
I was under the impression that you are using ruby on rails which means no need to write a sql query! If I'm wrong and you just want the sql query then you can find an answer in the comments!

Comment: I know very little about rails, so yea if he wants the query just follow the comments... if its building it all in rails then i guess he doesn't need the sql :) thanks for the edit